# Not able to get the interactive elements working from 3rd party UI library (Flowbite)

Tags: javascript, svelte, flowbite

I'm using Svelte (not kit) and trying to use Flowbite.js (not flowbite-svelte) with it.

When I use, for example, a dropdown from Flowbite in Navbar, **it toggles properly on the first page load** but when the component is switched (via router), the toggling doesn't work anymore.

I'm using Flowbite via CDN (https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/#include-via-cdn) and added the JS file before the end of the body tag as instructed.

When checking the console, no error shows up.

However when I tried to save the JS file and manually import it my App.svelte and then the below error popped up:

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')".

Which makes me think that it's not able to read the buttons/dropdowns.

```
<div type="button" id="menu-dropdownButton" data-dropdown-toggle="menu-dropdown">
   <span>Menu</span>
</div>


<div id="menu-dropdown">
    <ul aria-labelledby="menu-dropdownButton">
        <li>
            <span type="button" data-drawer-target="drawer-right" data-drawer-show="drawer-right" data-drawer-placement="right" aria-controls="drawer-right">Settings</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Overview</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I use Flowbite on a non-svelte website, everything works.

Is there any way to get it working?

I know about flowbite-svelte but I don't want that complications for simple elements. I prefer to use the CDN version.

However when I tried to save the JS file and manually import it my App.svelte and then the below error pops up:

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')".